# How to back up and restore a gitlab runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab runner on a small Linux box. I need to reinstall the OS on that box, and I'd like to not have to set up the gitlab runner from scratch after the reinstall. (I'm using the SaaS gitlab.com for my repo and CI, not my own instance.) What config files etc. do I need to back up and restore to keep my same gitlab runner working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to back up, really. The runner itself is just coordinating jobs.

If you want to not need to register the runner, you could theoretically backup the `config.toml` file which would prevent you from needing to re-register the runner, but the only thing that the runner installs per-se is the binary, which you'll have to re-install on the new box.

Comment: Thanks! Backing up and restoring `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` after reinstalling the gitlab-runner package worked perfectly. The runner came right back up with its same config and was shown as online in gitlab.